# Read data from current google-calendar tab without Oauth

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to use calendar.events.list to get a list of the events on the currently displayed calendar, without authorisation?

My thought was that if the tab was showing the calendar then maybe it was already authorised?

Comment: it's authorized. you could capture the access token or use the cookie. have you tried either?

Comment: Cheers Zig, I don't really know how to do that, I'm completely new to Chrome

Comment: check this link https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity which has information about user authentication in chrome